# What is the core difference between strings and numbers in Common Lisp?

Tags: string, list, numbers, common-lisp

Being new with CL, I play a lot with simple algorithms. For instance, I tried to implement a function for removing all unique elements in a list.

`(1 2 2 3 3 4 5 3) -> (2 2 3 3 3)`

First attempt lead to this code:

```
(defun remove-unique (items)
  (let ((duplicates (set-difference items (remove-duplicates items :test #'equal))))
    (append duplicates (remove-duplicates duplicates :test #'equal))))
```

This works ok with strings but does always return `NIL` for numbers. Reading a bit more about `set-difference` I've learned that it isn't suppose to work with duplicate populated lists at all, it just works somehow in my case, so I abandoned the approach as unportable and moved along.

Another attempt is:

```
(defun remove-unique (items)
  (loop for item in items 
    when (member item (cdr (member item items)))
    collect item))
```

And this works ok with numbers, but returns `NIL` for strings.

Apparently there is a core difference between strings and numbers I don't understand. How come list processing functions such as `member` and `set-difference` work differently on them?

Comment: `member` also takes a predicate which specifies what kind of comparison you want t apply to list items.

Comment: Thanks! I really did forget about it. But it is still `NIL` for strings.

Comment: It was indeed missed `test`, I just fed it the list with no duplicates when testing the second time :-) No wonder it gave me nil.

Comment: Your second example (because of the edit that adds `:test #'equal`) works.  E.g., `(remove-unique (list "1" "2" "2")) => ("2" "2"))`.  When the code in the question is no longer broken, it's not really a question anymore.  Could you undo your edit, so that the question still makes sense (and the answers to it still make sense)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are more related to lists than numbers since both lists and strings are sequences.

`"Hello"` is a sequence (compund data type) starting with the primitive character value `#\H` and ending with `#\o`.

`'(1 2 3)` is a sequence (compond data type) starting with the primitive numeric value 1 and ending with 3.

Characters are similar to numbers in that they are primitive values. Primitive values can be compared using `eql` while sequences, that are not the same object, can be compared using `equal`

```
(setq list1 (list 1 2 3))
(setq list2 (list 1 2 3))

(eql list1 list2) 
;==> NIL

(equal list1 list2)
;==> T

;; comparing first element of both lists using eql
(eql (car list1) (car list2))
;==> T

(setq string1 "Hello")
(setq string2 "Hello")

(eql string1 string2)
;==> NIL

(equal string1 string2)
;==> T

;; comparing first character of both strings using eql
(eql (elt string1 0) (elt string2 0))
;==> T
```

Most (if not all) functions in Common Lisp that compares something usually has an optional named argument `:test` where you can supply how elements compare. the default usually is `eql`. To make them behave corretly with sequences you need to supply `#'equal` as `:test`.

Answer (score 2):

The equality comparison for numbers, characters and strings is indeed different. Equal, which you should be wary to use because it is more expensive, does structure equality (so it descends on some objects). eq does object equality. And eql does object equality for most cases except for numbers (where they check type and value) and characters (where they check 'value')

See the hyperspec entries for [equal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm), [eql](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm) and [eq](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun remove-unique (items &key (test 'eql))
  (loop
     :with table := (make-hash-table :test test)
     :for element :in items :do
     (setf (gethash element table)
           (1+ (gethash element table 0)))
     :finally
     (return
       (loop
          :for k :being :the :hash-keys :of table
          :using (:hash-value v)
          :when (> v 1) :nconc (make-list v :initial-element k)))))

(defun remove-unique (items &key (test 'eql))
  (loop
     :with table := (make-hash-table :test test)
     :for element :in items :do
     (setf (gethash element table)
           (1+ (gethash element table 0)))
     :finally
     (return
       (loop
          :for element :in items
          :unless (= 1 (gethash element table))
          :collect element))))
```

I'd probably use the first variant because it makes less reads from hash-table, but you'd need to check that items in the list aren't modified later in place.

```
(remove-unique '("1" "2" "2" "3" "3" "4" "5" "3") :test #'equal)
```

gives:

```
("2" "2" "3" "3" "3")
```

but

```
(remove-unique '("1" "2" "2" "3" "3" "4" "5" "3"))
```

gives:

```
NIL
```